# "WinError 10061" When trying to connect to Cloud SQL using Cloud SQL Python Connector

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, pymysql, connection-refused

I have created a Cloud SQL instance, and a new database. However, I can't seem to connect to the database using [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector). I have followed the sample code and steps in the documentation, but still failed.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\my_name\my_path\gl_cloudsql_mysql_fx.py", line 149, in <module>
    print(bnm_data_db.isTableExist('MY_TABLE'))
  File "c:\Users\my_name\my_path\gl_cloudsql_mysql_fx.py", line 81, in isTableExist
    with self.__pool.connect() as db_conn:
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3245, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3269, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 455, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1270, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 719, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 905, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 901, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 368, in <lambda>
    return lambda rec: creator_fn()
  File "c:\Users\my_name\my_path\gl_cloudsql_mysql_fx.py", line 27, in getconn
    conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = self.__connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\sql\connector\connector.py", line 154, in connect
    return connect_task.result()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\sql\connector\connector.py", line 261, in connect_async
    return await asyncio.wait_for(get_connection(), timeout)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\sql\connector\connector.py", line 257, in get_connection
    return await self._loop.run_in_executor(None, connect_partial)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\sql\connector\pymysql.py", line 54, in connect
    socket.create_connection((ip_address, SERVER_PROXY_PORT)),
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\envs\composer-bis-gl-env\lib\socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I run this python code on locally on my machine (in a Conda environment).

Here's my code:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql

connector = Connector()

# function to return the database connection
def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
    conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
      "my_project:my_location:my_instance",
      "pymysql",
      user="user",
      password="password",
      db="my_database",
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
  "mysql+pymysql://",
  creator=getconn,
)

# insert statement
check_table_statement = sqlalchemy.text(
  "SELECT count(*) from information_schema.tables",
)

with pool.connect() as db_conn:
  result = db_conn.execute(check_table_statement)
  print(result)

connector.close()
```

I have tried to include my IP address in the Cloud SQL instance. However, I am not sure which one is the correct address. I have check my IP address multiple ways, but all of them are different:

1. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip)
2. [whatsmyip.org](https://www.whatsmyip.org/)
3. cmd command `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`

No luck with all of them.

**Note:**

- I did not check the `Allow only SSL connections` box. So, I reckon, there is no need to include the CA certificate.
- The CloudSQL instance is using Public IP.

**Update:**
I have added full error.

Comment: were you able to get the Python Connector working?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, check the following -

1. Make sure you enabled Public IP on the Cloud SQL instance
2. Then, create a user with hosts allowed as `%` (all IPs).
3. Next, ensure that you have a database created by the name of `my_database` by clicking on the `Databases` button on the left navigation inside Cloud SQL dashboard.
4. Ensure that you are including the right service credentials in your script with `Cloud SQL Client` role.

You should be able to connect. Do let me know if you face any issues, will update the answer accordingly :)

Comment: @Bismuth Habs were you able to resolve your issue using these steps? If not I can jump in and try to offer more assistance.

Comment: @xprilion it seems that I am still unable to connect to Cloud SQL. As a temporary workaround, currently I use Cloud Editor to run my python code instead. And it is working.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon no luck :( . Yes please jump in.

Comment: @BismuthHabs what error message are you facing currently?

Comment: @BismuthHabs are you trying to connect to a Public IP or Private IP Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: @xprilion the same error.  "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: @JackWotherspoon Public IP, I leave it on default. Sorry missed to mention that on my question. I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things for you to try in order to resolve the `ConnectionRefusedError`.

1. Make sure [the Cloud SQL Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com) is enabled within your Google Cloud Project.
2. Make sure the IAM principal you are using for authorization within your environment has the [Cloud SQL Client Role](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/roles-and-permissions) granted to it.
3. Double check that your instance connection name is correct (first argument being passed to the `.connect` method) by verifying it on the [Cloud SQL instance overview page](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql).
4. If you are connecting to a Cloud SQL instance Private IP make sure you are connecting from a machine within the VPC network and that your code is updated for private IP connections:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql

connector = Connector()

# function to return the database connection
def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
    conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
      "my_project:my_location:my_instance",
      "pymysql",
      user="user",
      password="password",
      db="my_database",
      ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE,
    )
    return conn
```

Let me know if any of these help resolve your connection, otherwise I can take a deeper look into it for you :)

Comment: No. 1,2,3 ... check... 
No. 4. The instance is using Public IP.

Still the same error. If there is anything else you need to know, let me know.

Comment: I have added the full error in my question.

Comment: @BismuthHabs how are you setting Application Default Credentials? What command/method are you using to set credentials?

Comment: You will want to make sure that credentials are being set properly in your conda environment.

Comment: Thanks! #4 was the culprit in my case..